# New column from non-standard date factor in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with an oddly formatted dates column. I'd like to create a column just showing the year from the original date column and I am having trouble coming up with a way to do this because the current date column is being treated as a factor. Any advice on how to do this efficiently would be appreciated.

Example
starting with:

```
org <- c("a","b","c","d")
country <- c("1","2","3","4")
date <- c("01-09-14","01-10-07","11-31-99","10-31-12")
toy <- data.frame(cbind(org,country,date))
toy
  org country     date
1   a       1 01-09-14
2   b       2 01-10-07
3   c       3 11-31-99
4   d       4 10-31-12

str(toy$date)
Factor w/ 4 levels "01-09-14","01-10-07",..: 1 2 4 3
```

Desired result:

```
  org country     Year
1   a       1     2014
2   b       2     2007
3   c       3     1999
4   d       4     2012
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for pointing out the error in my toy example (Nov. 31 can't exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
transform(toy,Year=format(strptime(date,"%m-%d-%y"),"%Y"))
```

This produces

```
##   org country     date Year
## 1   a       1 01-09-14 2014
## 2   b       2 01-10-07 2007
## 3   c       3 11-31-99 <NA>
## 4   d       4 10-31-12 2012
```

I initially thought that the `NA` value was because the `%y` format indicator wasn't smart enough to handle previous-century dates, but `?strptime` says:

> ‘%y’ Year without century (00-99).  On input, values 00 to 68 are
>             prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 - that is the behaviour
>             specified by the 2004 and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do
>             also say ‘it is expected that in a future version the default
>             century inferred from a 2-digit year will change’.

implying that it should be able to handle it.

The problem is actually that 31 November doesn't exist ...

(You can drop the `date` column at your leisure ...)